# Spark, with tons of memory, failing to join dataframes due to OOM

Tags: scala, apache-spark, heap-memory, hadoop-yarn

We're using Spark at work to do some batch jobs, but now that we're loading up with a larger set of data, Spark is throwing java.lang.OutOfMemory errors. We're running with Yarn as a resource manager, but in client mode.

- Driver memory = 64gb
- Driver cores = 8
- Executors = 8
- Executor memory = 20gb
- Executor cores = 5
- Deploy mode = client

The driver first makes many network queries to other services to get data, which it writes in chunks of compressed parquet (using Spark) to many temporary sub-directories of the main batch directory. In aggregate we're talking about 100,000,000 case classes with ~40 properties written to compressed parquet using Spark -> dataframe -> parquet. This part works fine.

Once that work is done, we have two sets of data: people and animals. We need to join the animals on the id of the people they belong to. But first, we clean up a bunch of animal date columns to make sure they look right (birthdays, vaccination dates, etc.).

The amount of memory housed in each animal or people sub-directory is not massive. It's actually quite small - maybe 100kb per directory and ~800 directories. Again, it's snappy-compressed parquet.

Previously, the final size of the joined directory's parquet was about 130 **mega**bytes. I think with our new data we'll have about double that, but I just don't understand how we hit memory issues during this process.

I would greatly appreciate any wisdom anyone has to offer.

Here are some methods used in this joining process:

```
  def fromHdfs(path) {
    // Construct Seq of sub-directories with data...
    val dataframes = dirs.map(dir => spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").load(s"$root/$dir"))
    // Concatenate each dataframe into one resulting df
    dataframes.reduce(_ union _)
  }

  private def convertDates(df: DataFrame, dateCols: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
   // Clean up dates from a pre-determined list of 'dateCol' strings
   df.columns.intersect(dateCols).foldLeft(df)((newDf, col) =>
      newDf
        .withColumn(col, unix_timestamp(df(col).cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd")
          .cast("timestamp")
          .cast("date")
        ))
  }

  // Join the people and animals dataframes on 'id'
  def peopleWithAnimals(people: DataFrame, animals: DataFrame)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    // The only collect in here, just to get the column names to foldLeft over
    val cols = animals.select("animal").distinct.select("animal").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect().map(_.toString)
    val animalsReshaped = cols.foldLeft(animals) { (newDf, colName) =>
      newDf.withColumn(colName, when($"animal" === colName, animals("value")).otherwise(null))
    }
    val peopleNoDups = people.dropDuplicates()
    val animalsNoDups = animalsReshaped.dropDuplicates()
    convertDates(peopleNoDups.join(animalsNoDups, "id"), dateCols)
  }
```

The above methods are used in the final method, the entirety of which is as follows:

```
def writeJoined(....) = {
  // Read all of the animal and people data subdirectories into dataframes
  val animals = Read.animalsFromHdfs(sourcePath)
  val people = Read.ownersFromHdfs(sourcePath)

  // Join the dataframes on id
  val joined = Join.peopleWithAnimals(animals, people)

  // Write the result to HDFS.
  joined.write.option("header", "true").parquet(destinationPath)
}
```

Our application now gets as far as creating the temporary directory that the joined data will be written to, but runs out of memory somewhere in the process after that.

```
18/06/14 20:37:39 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1196.0 in stage 1320.0 (TID 61383) in 1388 ms on machine-name (executor 8) (1242/24967)
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2018/06/14 20:38:39 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/appfolder/core.20180614.203839.27070.0001.dmp' in response to an event
```

and

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryErrorException in thread "Spark Context Cleaner" Exception in thread "DataStreamer for file /spark2-history/application_1527888960577_0084.inprogress block BP-864704807-49.70.7.82-1525204078667:blk_1073896985_156181" Exception in thread "SparkListenerBus" Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Exception in thread "RequestSenderProxy-ts" Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Exception in thread "task-result-getter-0"
 Exception in thread "task-result-getter-3" Exception in thread "heartbeat-receiver-event-loop-thread" 
Exception in thread "LeaseRenewer:valrs_dev_usr@companyhost:companyport" java/lang/OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```